# mysql query insert issue

Tags: php, mysql

my query is not inserting and i'm not getting any errors. can't figure out why it's not inserting

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $clean[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$entry = "INSERT INTO test (Word, Type, Lang, Country, Gender, Advice, y_Advice, Notes, 
EditorNotify, Equiv) 
VALUES('".$clean["word_field"]."', 
'".$clean["type_field"]."', 
'".$clean["lang"]."', 
'".$clean["Country"]."', 
'".$clean["gender"]."', 
'".$clean["advice"]."', 
'".$clean["y_advice"]."', 
'".$clean["Notes"]."',
'".($clean["Notes"] != '' ? '1' : '')."',
'".$clean["Equiv"]."')";
echo mysql_query ($entry);
mysql_query ($entry);
```

Comment: Do a `echo mysql_error();` to see errors

Comment: What's the output from `echo mysql_error();` after your query executes? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: maybe you dont enter to condition because $_POST['submit'] is not set

Comment: @Haim you're right, it's 10 to 10. I was too quick :)

Comment: @Pekka no errors. can I use the for name something like set a form name to add_entry then do something like if(isset($_POST['add_entry']))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually doing the insert twice because of this:

```
echo mysql_query ($entry);
mysql_query ($entry);
```

The `echo` line will run the query, and so will the line after it. You need to get rid of that. (though I guess you only put it in there for testing purposes?)

Instead of that, I'd suggest just echoing `$entry` itself, so you get to see the finished SQL string. You may spot something wrong with the query right away just from that.

If you don't, then try copying+pasting that string into a SQL query program to see what the actual error is. That'll allow you to play with the query until you get it right.

You could also use the PHP command `mysql_error()` to get the error out of PHP, but it's when you've got a weird SQL error, it can often be quicker and easier to play with the query directly rather than within the PHP code.

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks that helped me, echoing $entry I noticed that two fields where not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
(Word, Type, Lang, Country, Gender, Advice, y_Advice, Notes, 
EditorNotify, Equiv)
```

With:

```
(`Word`, `Type`, `Lang`, `Country`,`Gender`, `Advice`, `y_Advice`, `Notes`, 
`EditorNotify`, `Equiv`)
```

Comment: None of the column names are in the MySQL list of reserved words, so this shouldn't make any difference

Comment: @Mark though it's always worth to do it

Answer (score 1):

You don't know whether you're getting any errors.  First, get rid of `echo mysql_query()`.  Then run:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

If `mysql_query()` returns `false`, which it does upon failure, whatever MySQL error the query generated will now be printed to the screen.

Just a minor note: you should initialize `$clean` with `$clean = array();`

If the problem is that the conditional is not firing, then the problem may be elsewhere.  Do you have an `<input>` named "submit" in your form, and is the method of the form `post`?

Query itself looks okay to me.  I think it is difficult to read, so I would do this, but that's just personal style:

```
$notify = $clean['Notes'] != '' ? '1' : '';
$query = <<<SQL
  INSERT INTO test
     (Notes, EditoryNotify)
  VALUES 
     ($clean[Notes], $notify)
```

SQL;